# Rspec before(:each) works but before(:all) does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

My ProductCategory spec:-

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ProductCategory, type: :model do
    before(:each) do 
        @product_category = create(:product_category)
    end

  context "validations" do 
    it "should have valid factory" do
        expect(@product_category).to be_valid
    end

    it "should have unique name" do 
        product_category_new = build(:product_category, name: @product_category.name)
        expect(product_category_new.save).to be false
    end
  end
end
```

The spec runs fine, but when I use before(:all) instead of before(:each), second example fails -
`expected false got true` I know the difference between before(:all) and before(:each) but I am not able to find the exact reason why second example fails with before(:all)

Comment: Fails with what error?

Comment: Fails with expectation errors? Or with  some other error?
Do I guess correctly that category name should be unique? Do you use database cleaner or `config.use_transactional_fixtures`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`before :all` only runs once before all the examples, so the `@product_category` is created once. If you have a something like a DatabaseCleaner truncation running after each test, the record is no longer in the database in the second test, thus passing the validation.

`before :each` on the other hand will be run before each example, so the record will be there in the second example even if the database was cleaned in the meantime.